# Redis Database Vs Redis Cache

Tags: redis

Could you please answer these 2 questions and correct me if wrong.

I assume Both **Redis Database** and **Redis Cache** are stored in Memory and **not** in Disk. Am I correct?

If Yes, What are the major difference between both. I am assuming both are stored in memory and it should not make much difference between them both. I mean the speed should be the same as they are in memory only. Do we still need Cache again?

Could you please tell me what are the differences and advantages between the both.

Second Question:  Can the server restart remove all data in the Redis database? Cache must be deleted for sure I believe.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what do you mean?
Redis is a product first of all - its an in-memory data structures store.

Depending on its configurations it can be targeted to different use cases:

- Database
- Cache
- Even message broker

If you're coming from the cloud world, cloud providers can call this "Cache" and this means that they offer a redis that is pre-configured to be used as a cache (remove the oldest records when the memory becomes next to be fully utilized, etc).
But after you'll you will work with some kind of redis client that will interact with remote redis server.

Comment: HI Mark, Thanks a lot for your reply. I know it has differnt capabilities like Datbase , Cahce and message broker used by Celary. My Question is  "If both Redis Database" and "Cache" are stored in Memory and both are super fast the why should I again use Cache. Anyhow let me explore further on this. Upvoted your reply.

Comment: Hi Chakra, I think I understood your question. Redis, as an in-memory database is supposed to provide its services over a network. A redis server stands in the network to provide caching services. This way, clients will make network request to it. A local in-memory cache may be used by each client to cache the results to avoid this round trip for the next calls. Several Redis clients implements local memory caching using several algorithms.